# array default- vs. list-initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, c++11, list-initialization

I have the following code, a simplification of an array-like structure:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct X
{
    T a[N];

    template<typename... A>
    explicit X(A&&... a) : a{std::forward<A>(a)...} { }  // ERROR (2)
};

int main ()
{
    X<int,3> x;           // OK
    X<X<int,3>,2> y{x,x}; // OK
    X<X<int,3>,2> z;      // ERROR (1)
}
```

This is compiling fine in clang 3.3 and gcc 4.8.1, both with `-std=c++11`. I am trying to upgrade gcc, so I now try 4.9.0. In this case, the 3rd example (`ERROR (1)`) instantiates `X`'s constructor (`ERROR (2)`), at which point the compiler reports

```
error: converting to 'X<int, 3ul>' from initializer list would use explicit
   constructor 'X<T, N>::X(A&&...) [with A = {}; T = int; long unsigned int N = 3ul]
```

This last example attempts to default-initialize array `z` and so also its included arrays; however, if I get this right, here gcc essentially says that the included arrays are being list-initialized by `{}`, which is not allowed since the constructor is explicit.

The error is gone if I add another default constructor of either of the following forms:

```
explicit X() {}
explicit X() : a() {}
```

but **not**

```
explicit X() : a{} {}
```

This workaround is not difficult, but any idea who's wrong and who's right, just so I know what I'm doing and why?

Comment: The simplest fix is to add `X() : a{} {}` (without the `explicit`). I think this is related to http://gcc.gnu.org/PR60416 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518

Comment: I think this is a GCC 4.9 regression, which I've reported to bugzilla, but as issue 1518 shows, the standard isn't really clear what should happen.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The real simplest fix is to use `std::array` and get the same functionality without reinventing the wheel :-P

Comment: @MadScienceDreams No. using `std::array<T,N> a;` instead of `T a[N];` does not change anything. The problem remains.

Comment: No, I meant using an std::array instead of X.

Comment: @JonathanWakely adding `X() : a{} {}` would allow me to write `X<T,N> x = {};` which I want to avoid. Why is it better than the two fixes I mention above?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I one's happy with the functionality of `std::array`, I agree. But if you want to add anything, you're breaking its being an aggregate before you know it, and then it's too late.

Comment: Because the default constructor is not `explicit`, but I didn't realise that was a design goal. Personally I love being able to pass `{}` to functions or assign it to things, so I never (for some value of never) want an explicit default ctor

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well, there's an implementation and an interface (or maybe other layers in between). I usually keep everything in implementations explicit so I can sleep easier at night, but it's not such a hard choice. It may change if there is good reason, but will take thought and testing.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I checked [gcc.gnu.org/PR60416](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR60416). The test case given appears very similar, but is in fact accepted by my 4.9.0. So it may be something else.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for the remaining pointers. I can't say I can draw any conclusion but anyhow I'll pick one of the 2-3 choices and move on.

Comment: Follow the link from PR60416 to http://gcc.gnu.org/PR60417 and you'll see the original testcase was fixed, but I've added an new testcase as a comment. It's the same issue.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Wow I've just now seen your new post, thanks. The testcase of your [Comment 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60417#c5) works here, but both cases of [Comment 6](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60417#c6) reproduce the error. I can't see what the difference may be.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Please feel free to post this info as an answer.

Comment: Comment 5 (which is the same as the original testcase, and thus fixed in the current trunk) doesn't involve an array. Comment 6 involves an array, as I state in comment 6 :-)

Comment: Ok, now it's clear, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a GCC bug, [PR 60417](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR60417).

An older change for [PR 54835](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR54835) was intended to implement the C++ committee's proposed direction for fixing [core issue 1518](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518). Unfortunately that change breaks some valid C++03 programs, as shown by the first example in PR 60417. A fix was committed for PR 60417, but it only handles some cases. Specifically, it doesn't fix the case where list-initializing an array of types with explicit constructors, as in this question.